# SetUp : System.Exception : ApkFile or InstalledApp has not been configured

Tags: android, mobile, xamarin, ui-automation

i'm Working on xamarin forms simple app (CreditCardValidator) i downloaded the app from [https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/test-cloud/Quickstarts/CreditCardValidator.Droid/]

Now is it possible to start Running Test Method  without providing path to (.apk File) ... if not i want to know how to start VS emulator just after Running Test method ( running test method to automatically launch VS emulator ) ?

```
public class Tests
{
    AndroidApp app;

    [SetUp]
    public void BeforeEachTest()
    {
        app = ConfigureApp.Android.StartApp();
    }

    [Test]
    public void CreditCardNumber_TooShort_DisplayErrorMessage()
    {
        app.WaitForElement(c => c.Marked("action_bar_title").Text("Enter Credit Card Number"));
        app.EnterText(c=>c.Marked("creditCardNumberText"), new string('9', 15));
        app.Tap(c => c.Marked("validateButton"));

        app.WaitForElement(c => c.Marked("errorMessagesText").Text("Credit card number is too short."));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If there is only one device attached to the computer, and no running simulators, then UITest will automatically run the tests on the device.

This would also apply to an emulator in the sense that it would have to be already up and running.

**Source:** https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/working-with/testing-on-devices/android/#Programmatically_Declaring_the_Device

However since you might need to boot an emulator up, you can do the following:

There is a tool called `emulatorcmd.exe` that you can use. It is found in the following directory on Windows:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Emulator Manager\1.0`

You can use `emulatorcmd.exe list /sku:Android /type:device /state:installed` to get a list of available emulators that are installed.

You can then use `emulatorcmd.exe launch /sku:Android /id:<id>` which will launch that specific emulator.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2014/11/12/introducing-visual-studios-emulator-for-android/

Comment: @ Jon i used 

app = ConfigureApp.Android.ApkFile(path).DeviceSerial("363F7AED-462C-46BD-9FEC-F1DD3B79916C").StartApp();

but it did not work
is there are any way to run on emulator without being running ? ( test method to launch emulator ? )

Comment: I do not believe the testing framework will bootup an emulator for you. You will have to make a custom build script to invoke this emulator and wait a minute or so before invoking `nunit-console.exe` to run your UI Tests.